# BeautifulSoup extracting multiple table

Tags: python, html-table, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to extract some data from two tables from the same HTML with BeautifulSoup. Actually, I already extracted part from both tables but not all. This is the code that I have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = urlopen('https://www.icewarehouse.com/Bauer_Vapor_X25_Ice_Hockey_Skates/descpage-V25XS.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class' : 'orderingtable fl'})

for table_skates in tables:

    t_headers = []
    t_data = []
    t_row = {}

    for tr in table_skates.find_all('th'):

        t_headers.append(tr.text.replace('\n', '').strip())

    for td in table_skates.find_all('td'):

        t_data.append(td.text.replace('\n', '').strip())

    t_row = dict(zip(t_headers, t_data))

    print(t_row)
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
{'Size': '1.0', 'Price': '$109.99', 'Stock': '1', 'Qty': ''}
{'Size': '7.0', 'Price': '$159.99', 'Stock': '2+', 'Qty': ''}
```

Comment: It's because your lists have different length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get it by using 'read_html' in 'pandas'.

```
df = pd.read_html(html_content, attrs={'class' : 'orderingtable fl'})
```

[image]